# Parsing string by line using java

Tags: java

I have below string ,each line dont have new line characters.I want to read upto 4 lines and

form the 2 output strings. one is CODE1;CODE2;CODE3;CODE4 and other is data1;data2;data3;data4. I am not sure how to split this string each line as there is no new line character. Please help or guide me to solve this problem.

```
/CODE1/data1 (upto 35 chars length)
/CODE2/data2 (upto 35 chars length)
/CODE3/data3 (upto 35 chars length)
/CODE4/data4 (upto 35 chars length)
...
....
...
/CODEn/datan (upto 35 chars length)
```

code:

```
String str="/CODE1/data1"+
"/CODE2/data2"+
"/CODE3/data3"+
"/CODE4/data4";
String a[] =str.split("/");
for(int k=0;k<a.length;k++)
System.out.println(a[k]);
```

Not sure how to restrict upto 4 lines and separate the code and data.

Comment: Do a read up, with something like split("/"), you should have a clue on what next. Your question isn't very clear by the way.

Comment: I think that you can use stringTokenizer I let you a link where there is a good example http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/

Comment: How to restrict in code to read upto 4 lines and how to separate code and values.

Comment: forgot to add code.edited my question

Comment: If the lines do not contain newline characters then why do you call them lines? What is the exact format of the input text? Please explain your problem more clearly in the question.

Comment: exact format i given my code snippet ,code and data separated by "/".i want to separate them into 2 strings like code1;code2;code3;code4; and data1;data2;dat3;data4 after split .but input string contain n number of lines(sorry not sure how to call this as).what i mean is even input string contain code5 and data5.but i shouldn't consider this.

Answer (score 0):

String.split() takes a regular expression.  Therefore, if you're trying to split on special characters like '/' or '.' you have to enclose them in brackets, like so:

`String[] parts = myString.split("[/]");`

Also, I agree the question is a little unclear, especially around the part about reading up to 4 lines from input that doesn't have newline characters.

Comment: i agree with you Russ,that is the reason question is here. in string ,how to estimate 5 th line if there is no new line character in the end for each line?.suppoese take if there is new line character for each line in string.how to restrict upto 4 lines and how to separate code and value.

Comment: it looks to me like the data is in pairs, so when it is split on '/' every two array values would constitute one line.  so, just process 4 pairs if only 4 'lines' are desired